# Where can I find materials about indexing and page ranking?

Tags: search-engine

I'm working on a large search engine system.

However, I'm not familiar with the background.

Where can I find materials about indexing and page ranking?

Answer (score 0):

[Modern information Retrieval](http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~hearst/irbook/)

[image: Modern information Retrieval]

A very known and a good book that will introduce you to these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can always look at the google research [stuff](http://research.google.com/). It is naturally very intense stuff but interesting none the less.